# SimpleDB select modified items

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, boto, boto3, amazon-simpledb

Is it possible to select modified items on a SimpleDB domain?

I have a large database and I would like to know daily which items were modified. I know I could add a new field and update it on every change of the record, but I want to know if it there is something like this built in the database for me to use without changing the records.

I am accessing SimpleDB with boto.

---

**Edit:

I am searching more or less to some hooks or triggers on SimpleDB that I can use to know about creation/update/delete events**

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no such feature in `Amazon SimpleDB`.

However, I would like to think that since this use-case can be easily entertained using a `created_at` and `updated_at` field, there really is no need to have such a feature in the database core.

Comment: but I would also not know if something was deleted.

Comment: @JBernardo Add **is_active** flag to mark deleted items, you may have recurring job to permanently delete the items. SimpleDB as the name suggests was designed for a very basic reason and the functionality you are demanding needs some advanced database concepts that is available in AWS RDS.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in feature to accomplish this.
Here is the relevant documentation:

- Developer Guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingSelect.html
- FAQs: https://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/faqs/
- Guide - Databases on AWS: https://aws.amazon.com/products/databases/

Anyway, depending on your specific use-case, these may be acceptable solutions:

1. after updating an item, your app could log somewhere the Key (ID) of the document being updated (S3, DynamoDB, other SDB Domains, ...). Then you can easily fetch all the items updated this day.
2. instead of a SimpleDB Domain, you could use a DynamoDB Table with a Global Secondary Index to Query, or (better) use trigger to log all the changes like in (1)

Comment: I am searching more or less to some hooks or triggers on SimpleDB that I can use to know about creation/update/delete events

Comment: I can't think of a way to to this. Unfortunately, SimpleDB is not tracked by CloudTrail: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-supported-services.html#cloudtrail-supported-services-database